# Can you rename members when using typedef?

Tags: c++, struct, typedef, member

I'm using a struct of three `float`s to represent Translation and Scale like this:

```
typedef struct Translation{
    Translation() : x(0.0), y(0.0), z(0.0){};
    Translation(x, y, z) : x(x), y(y), z(z){};
    //some arithmetic operators
    float x, y, z;
}
Translation;

typedef Translation Scale;
```

Now I would want to use this definition to represent Rotation as well, but I don't want to access their members as `x`, `y` and `z`, but `yaw`, `pitch` and `roll`. Is it possible to rename members like this via a `typedef`? Or is there another way which does not include redefining the complete struct and its members?

Comment: No. `typedef` is for types. `x`, `y`, `z` are not types.

Comment: Don't do this. `Translation`, `Scale`, and `Rotation` are all different concepts. The fact that they all contain three `float`s is incidental, not a good reason to share code between them. `typedef` doesn't copy a type to another type, it only creates an alias. So you would be able to pass a `Rotation` to a function expecting a `Scale` because they are just two names for the same type, which would subvert all notions of type safety.

Comment: @Oktalist very good point! I thought about inheritance for a second, but that raises the same problem. I guess I should just define all three separately.

Comment: Why are you so lazy and not just copy'n'paster code, do a search a replace? Seems a few minutes of work.

Comment: @EdHeal because as soon as I change something about a class, these changes won't be reflected in the other classes. Also, it means lots of redundant code that could probably be avoided.

Comment: @iFreilicht - SO? They are different concepts/objects. But you can just amalgamate them as just a 4 x 4 matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because typedef is for types (e.g. int, double, etc.).

The clearest way is to make another struct.

EDIT:
Since this is C++, I suggest you make a base class, that contains all the logic and derive from it. In other words, use ***inheritance***.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
 public:
  Base(int aa, int bb, int cc)
   : a(aa), b(bb),c(cc) {}

  int getA() {
    return a;
  }

  int getB() {
    return b;
  }

  int getC() {
    return c;
  }

  // Notice that you make the data members private,
  // but then you will need the getters to access them
  // in the derived classes
 protected:
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};

class A : public Base {
 public:
  A(int aa, int bb, int cc)
   : Base(aa, bb, cc) {}

  int x() {
    return a;
  }

  int y() {
    return b;
  }

  int z() {
    return c;
  }
};

class B : public Base {
 public:
  B(int aa, int bb, int cc)
   : Base(aa, bb, cc) {}

  int gama() {
    return a;
  }

  int beta() {
    return b;
  }

  int theta() {
    return c;
  }
};

int main() {
  A a_object(1, 2, 3);

  B b_object(4, 5, 6);

  std::cout << "a of a_object = " << a_object.x() << "\n";
  std::cout << "b of b_object = " << b_object.gama() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are correct about `typedef`, but I was searching for a way to avoid retyping everything. All three structs work exactly the same, even their arithmetic and assignment operators.

Comment: @iFreilicht, you posted your answer, while I was updating. Note that with my approach, you can extend and maintain your code, far more easier. :)

Comment: I don't really want any interoperability between the three classes, that's why I avoided it. Also, I liked the simplicity of `scale.x = 1` rather than `scale.setX(1)`. But yeah, macros are probably not the easiest to maintain way. Also note that it is not necessary to use `aa` in your code. Constructors like `Foo(int a) : a(a){};` are 100% defined behaviour in C++. (if I understood the docs correctly)

Comment: You could have the .x, by letting the data members to be public, but ok. I am not sure about the constructor thing you say.

Comment: I think you are right about the constructor. However, having the argument inside the body can cause errors. Thanks for informing me.

Comment: Oh and additionally, you could just append a _ to the private/protected members to indicate internal use.

Comment: Well, as you can make many more things with inheritance, than with a macro. :)

Answer (score -1):

So here is my go on this: It is probably not perfect, but allows for easy modification of all three `struct`s at the same time while retaining a clear separation of all three types, which is extremely important as @Oktalist pointed out. 
There should be no interoperability between the three types, so inheritance and `typedef` are not an option.

So, I found my relief in Macros:

```
#define THREE_FLOAT_STRUCT(NAME, X, Y, Z, X_STANDARD, Y_STANDARD, Z_STANDARD) typedef struct NAME{\
    NAME() : X(X_STANDARD), Y(Y_STANDARD), Z(Z_STANDARD){};\
    NAME(float X, float Y, float Z) : X(X), Y(Y), Z(Z){};\
    NAME operator+(const NAME& other) const{ return NAME(X + other.X, Y + other.Y, Z + other.Z); }\
    NAME operator-(const NAME& other) const{ return NAME(X - other.X, Y - other.Y, Z - other.Z); }\
    NAME operator*(float divisor) const{ return NAME(X * divisor, Y * divisor, Z * divisor); }\
    NAME operator/(float divisor) const{ return NAME(X / divisor, Y / divisor, Z / divisor); }\
    NAME& operator+=(const NAME& other){ X += other.X; Y += other.Y; Z += other.Z; return *this; }\
    NAME& operator-=(const NAME& other){ X -= other.X; Y -= other.Y; Z -= other.Z; return *this; }\
    NAME& operator*=(float divisor){ X *= divisor; Y *= divisor; Z *= divisor; return *this; }\
    NAME& operator/=(float factor){ X /= factor; Y /= factor; Z /= factor; return *this; }\
    float X, Y, Z;\
} NAME;

THREE_FLOAT_STRUCT(Rotation, roll, pitch, yaw, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
THREE_FLOAT_STRUCT(Translation, x, y, z, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
THREE_FLOAT_STRUCT(Scale, x, y, z, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

I personally like that solution. It is indeed a bit hard to read, but we're only talking about basic arithmetic operations, the code isn't anything too fancy and you can see on a glance which operators are defined.

If you got better solutions, feel free to post them as another answer.

Comment: ... And then write more code that is difficult to understand and maintain

Comment: Oh god please say you didn't actually use this. :(

Comment: don't do this. You are reducing maintainability and understandability to no real benefit. If you want different method names in OOP you inherit

Comment: @tenfour I felt very crazy today... so yes, I did. But I know it was wrong. It would probably win an award in code-golfing, at least.

Comment: @dkackman yeah, I experienced that immediately. Experimenting with it was definitely fun though, and I'm kind of proud that it works the way intended. (That itself already tells it's a bad idea.) I'm going with inheritance now.